# How to get content out of a google map info window?

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I'm using php and cURL to get the content of various websites.

This is a google map info window: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Now, I want to get the content that is in the info window. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the data within the infowindow is embedded in a script tag of the html itself, so downloading the html from the URL, and then creating a regular expression to extract the content of the infowindow (in this case the variable named contentString) is pretty easy to do.

Some websites will not be straightforward though, and a variety of approaches would need to be employed in order to collect the information. Dynamic websites may populate the contents of the info window by using an ajax call, or the content might be contained in a separate script or json file.  If you are determined to scrape the content of each of these sites,  you will likely have to do some custom coding for each individual site.

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at these to examples. I can't seem to figure out where the information is stored.

[example1](http://www.hm.com/se/store-locator#store=SE432)
[example2](http://www.ahlens.se/stores/index.html#:2fe05c6e-1c9c-4937-bf92-3eca7a751237)

Comment: The data for example 1 comes from a restful ajax call to http://www.hm.com/rest/storelocator/stores/1.0/locale/sv_SE/store/SE454/ with the "store id" being the last part of the query string). Example 2 comes from http://www.ahlens.se/system/modules/com.gridnine.opencms.modules.ahlens2/providers/store-details.jsp?__locale=sv but it seems to require a cookie in order for the results to be returned properly (you can easily see both of these by running Fiddler, and navigating to the example urls in your browser).

Comment: I have a couple of more websites that I cant figure out how to get the information. Can I contact you, Javram? You got my mail in my user info.